# Problem with friendly urls in php (multilple tables)

Tags: php, friendly-url

I have a problem to create a router in PHP to handle friendly urls in multiple tables.

There are more than 10 tables, but I will use as example just 3.

- Authors
- Books
- Themes

I want to the friendly url to be without any directory OR number.

It must be like this

Author

- domain.com/John-Legend
- domain.com/Cris-Mendes

Books

- domain.com/My-Histories-From-Europe
- domain.com/How-get-rich-fast

Themes

- domain.com/Romance
- domain.com/Technology

Each table has a field called "url". So, in authors table has a register with a url field "/John-Legend", another with "/Cris-Mendes", etc.

How can I do it, without having to search all 10 tables for a match in the field "url"?

I was thinking about to create a "index" table to map all friendly urls. So the router should read just this table, and it would "point" to the right table and register.

Does it make sense? Is there a better way?

Thanks!

Comment: Let's hope noone ever publishes a book called "Romance"

Comment: Why not `books/name`, `author/name` etc?

Comment: Wouldn't it be much easier to use urls like `domain.com/book/how-to-rich-fast` and `domain.com/theme/romance`?

Comment: It will be difficult to distinguish if `John-Legend` is an author, title or category without additional data. Only thing you can do is add some column in your database and then resolve it by value. I would anyway use `domain.tld/author/John-Legend` vs `domain.tld/book/How-get-rich-fast` routes in this case.

Comment: @u_mulder that's for SEO. It is very important for an e-commerce. domain.com/romance is much better than domain.com/theme/romance

Comment: Magento does it right?

Comment: For SEO purposes I'd rather use valid structure like `domain.tld/romance`, `domain.tld/romance/jane-legend`, `domain.tld/romance/jane-legend/how-to-get-in-love`. Still not sure about mixing all types at one level.